# App Crash (SIGABRT) only in AppStore Review, not in Sim or my Hardware

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, app-store

I recently updated a stable app which has been in the Store for over a year and well over a thousand downloads. Last updated 6/19. All fine.
This week I added a unique UserID to my Flurry start up in App Delegate and few extra flurry event calls in various view controllers to help track rare crashes (maybe 3 crashes reported in a year). App runs fine in Xcode Sim on a variety of devices, and in my real hardware both in debug and untethered. GIT compare confirms no other changes to codebase or XIBs, etc.  Last compile for AppStore on Xcode 10.x, now 11.1

App Store review fails with crash on launch, they tried three times and sent crash logs. I removed some of the mods (but not yet the UserID in AppDelegate) and resubmitted: same result. First time I sent it in the crash report said they tested on a 3rd Gen iPad, so I asked them to try the second time on an iPhone, the next set of crash reports had the device code as XXX! They ran 13.1.2, I tested on 13.1.3 and on 12.1.4 all OK

Here's the problem(s)
1) I dont see how to symbolicate the crash reports. To do so, Xcode requires the App's binary and dSYM (I have those), I dont have the Flurry dSYM, and OS Symbols for the hardware/OS where the test ran. I dont have a 3rd gen iPad (iPad11,3) to plug in and get the symbols for Xcode.  Is there an alternative path to symbolication in this circumstance.

2) I'm not sure that the symbols would help here anyway since it looks like the crash is deep in iOS frameworks (maybe abi, see below) after being called from my Main.  I know that these kinds of launch crashes frequently occur when storyboards have a defect, but I cant see one and the app runs fine locally on new and old phones and old iPads.  What would be my next steps when I can't replicate the crash (aside from removing the Flurry set UserID! (my next blind step!))?

UPDATE: I have now reverted all changes in the App back to last stable release in App Store (except a single bug fix where I needed to release a KVO Observer for users with old iOS).  The reverted App still fails App Store review!  The only diffs are in the storyboards where a bunch of Rects are different sizes because last open IB device was different than the last device in the repo from last submission. App runs fine on local sims and local hardware but still crashes on launch in App Store review.

```
{"app_name":"QueensDB","timestamp":"2019-10-30 15:28:10.12 -0700","app_version":"1.7","slice_uuid":"2133ecf9-943d-380e-9d2b-eb881e02a76f","adam_id":1369301260,"build_version":"2","share_with_app_devs":true,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 13.1.2 (17A860)","incident_id":"BB1B0B65-66BF-40B7-9017-7F8B14B57F58","name":"QueensDB"}  
Incident Identifier: BB1B0B65-66BF-40B7-9017-7F8B14B57F58  
CrashReporter Key:   1f7448b682620a373ff01cf8ae95a9238488a987  
Hardware Model:      iPad11,3  
Process:             QueensDB [90772]  
Version:             2 (1.7)  
AppStoreTools:       11A1002b  
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)  
Role:                Foreground  
Parent Process:      launchd [1]  




Date/Time:           2019-10-30 15:28:09.6488 -0700  
Launch Time:         2019-10-30 15:28:09.5818 -0700  
OS Version:          iPhone OS 13.1.2 (17A860)  
Release Type:        User  
Baseband Version:    n/a  
Report Version:      104  


Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)  
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000  
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY  
Triggered by Thread:  0  


Application Specific Information:  
abort() called  


Last Exception Backtrace:  
(0x184f6bc30 0x184c860c8 0x184e5b3ac 0x18897c810 0x18897cb2c 0x18855b700 0x18855b934 0x1884f6428 0x1889c59bc 0x1049975b8 0x104993ab4 0x188c935d8 0x18855b700 0x18855b934 0x1884f6428 0x188c928cc 0x1889c5b74 0x188920b94 0x188c935d8 0x18855b700 0x1884f6428 0x188c97784 0x18855b700 0x18855b934 0x1884f6428 0x188c926b0 0x188c952e8 0x18915a7d0 0x18915a660 0x1890007c4 0x189000d3c 0x188fff46c 0x1887a7710 0x188c537e8 0x1887a8248 0x1887a7c78 0x1887a8064 0x1887a78e8 0x1887ac098 0x188c6d214 0x188b80e90 0x188c6d1cc 0x1887abdb0 0x188c6d0b4 0x1887abc0c 0x188617630 0x1886160f4 0x188617360 0x188ffd91c 0x188ba2d7c 0x18a0d5014 0x18a0fbbd0 0x18a0e00f8 0x18a0fb864 0x184c1300c 0x184c15d50 0x18a122384 0x18a122030 0x18a12259c 0x184ee7260 0x184ee71b4 0x184ee6920 0x184ee17ec 0x184ee1098 0x18f04b534 0x1890017ac 0x10494a1c8 0x184d60f30)  


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread  
Thread 0 Crashed:  
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x0000000184d56ef4 0x184d31000 + 155380  
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x0000000184c77d1c 0x184c75000 + 11548  
2   libsystem_c.dylib             0x0000000184c07a54 0x184b91000 + 485972  
3   libc++abi.dylib               0x0000000184d1e3c8 0x184d1d000 + 5064  
4   libc++abi.dylib               0x0000000184d1e5c0 0x184d1d000 + 5568  
5   libobjc.A.dylib               0x0000000184c863a8 0x184c80000 + 25512  
6   libc++abi.dylib               0x0000000184d2b634 0x184d1d000 + 58932  
7   libc++abi.dylib               0x0000000184d2b5c0 0x184d1d000 + 58816  
8   libdispatch.dylib             0x0000000184c13020 0x184c10000 + 12320  
9   libdispatch.dylib             0x0000000184c15d50 0x184c10000 + 23888  
10  FrontBoardServices             0x000000018a122384 0x18a0c8000 + 369540  
11  FrontBoardServices             0x000000018a122030 0x18a0c8000 + 368688  
12  FrontBoardServices             0x000000018a12259c 0x18a0c8000 + 370076  
13  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000184ee7260 0x184e39000 + 713312  
14  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000184ee71b4 0x184e39000 + 713140  
15  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000184ee6920 0x184e39000 + 710944  
16  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000184ee17ec 0x184e39000 + 690156  
17  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000184ee1098 0x184e39000 + 688280  
18  GraphicsServices               0x000000018f04b534 0x18f048000 + 13620  
19  UIKitCore                     0x00000001890017ac 0x1885d1000 + 10684332  
20  QueensDB                       0x000000010494a1c8 0x104944000 + 25032  
21  libdyld.dylib                 0x0000000184d60f30 0x184d60000 + 3888
```

Comment: You should at least be able to symbolicate stack frame 20 which is in your app.  Have you tried a TestFlight build?

Comment: @Paul, Thanks for the reply!  Despite downloading the crash reports from the store, extracting the actual report from the website, adding the correct file extension, dragging it to the correct Organizer view pane, and using the Symbolicate dropdown, Xcode did not do anything.  However, to address stack frame 20, it must be "Main".  You see the same pattern in almost every stack trace of the main thread. "Main" doesn't give me any insight to where the problem might be in the launch.  Im going to remove the USERID stuff from the AppDelegate and rebuild with Xcode 11.2 which was released today.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, once the Store Reviewer send me a crash report on hardware/software version I could re-symbolicate, that the crash issue was my use of a SearchDisplayController which crashed while loading the initial view controller.

Interesting because the app runs fine on iOS 13.2 on my local hardware. Maybe there is a strictness setting I need to know about?

An Apple engineer provided the following information: The offending App must be thinned to reproduce the error: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/125520